# How to change the bar color in UIImagePicker?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to color the bars in the camera view black. None of the below approaches worked so far. There are 2 views that I want to change, the first with the camera icon and "cancel", the second with the "retake" and "use" buttons. Any ideas?

```
- (void)openCamera {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    picker.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = (UIImagePickerController *)navigationController;
    if((picker)&&(picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera))
    {
        picker.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
        picker.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
        picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have some luck using `UIAppearance`. Look up the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Very nice, was able to change all UIToolbars and UINavigationBars unfortunatelly the UIImagePicker seems to use something else.

Comment: Hm... interesting. I was under the impression that it was using a `UINavigationController`, which would have its own `UINavigationBar` ...

Comment: Have you tried setting the bar style to `UIBarStyleDefault` and using a `tintColor`?

Comment: UIBarStyleDefault and tintColor does not work. I checked the view-tree and I get: UIWindow -> UITransitionView -> UIView -> UILayoutContainerView -> UINavigationTransitionView. The last two classes are undocumented API, picker.view is the UILayoutContainerView, so guess we are not allowed to use it.

Comment: Hm, Interesting. You might be right, perhaps it's not possible to style the picker view.

Comment: The UIAppearance led me in the right direction, so I'll accept your answer, thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UIImagePickerController` `showsCameraControls` and `cameraOverlayView` to use a custom view over the `UIImagePickerController`. Setting the `showsCameraControls`value to NO will hide everything on the `UIImagePickerController` but the camera view. `cameraOverlayView` allow you to put your own view over the camera view. You can then create a view with your own bottom bar, your own buttons, ... and put it in front of the UIImagePicker.

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] init];
/* Customize overlayView with your bottomBar and button */
UIImagePickerController imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
/* Configure your UIImagePickerController for picture and/or video */
imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO; //Must be set to NO if you want to use the cameraOverlayView
imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;
overlayView = nil;
```

Unfortunately, with this method you must recreate all the buttons of the original `UIImagePickerController` view (the flash mode button, the options button, ...) if you want to use them, and you have to create your own navigation controller to go to the view with the "retake" and "use" buttons. However it's very simple to implement.

Comment: how would I go about implementing the navigation controller with the view & "retake" and "use" buttons?